# Edge browser Native File System removeEntry use

Tags: directory, microsoft-edge, native-file-system-api-js, file-system-access-api

I'm working with the newest version of Edge (Canary release 86.0.615.0) and I can get the new Native File System API showOpenFilePicker to let me access files but I can't find a reference to the directoryHandle functions including the removeEntry function if the user elects to remove the file. Am I missing a special flag? I have an Origin-Tracker code and I also have the experimental flag set for the Native File System API.

Comment: You could refer to the [official doc](https://wicg.github.io/native-file-system/#api-filesystemdirectoryhandle-removeentry) about how to use `removeEntry()` method. There're [some steps](https://wicg.github.io/native-file-system/#dom-filesystemdirectoryhandle-removeentry) you must run when you use the method. I also find the [TypeScript types for the spec](https://github.com/WICG/native-file-system/issues/151) and it also includes `FileSystemDirectoryHandle` interface which I think may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a directory handle, you can delete files or folders as in the example below:

```js
// Delete a file.
await directoryHandle.removeEntry('Abandoned Projects.txt');
// Recursively delete a folder.
await directoryHandle.removeEntry('Old Stuff', { recursive: true });
```

You can obtain a directory handle from the picker:

```js
const directoryHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker();
```

To iterate over the entries of a directory, you can use the code snippet below:

```js
for await (const entry of directoryHandle.values()) {
  console.log(entry.kind, entry.name);
}
```